# URL Automatic redirecting in WebView - Android

Tags: java, android, android-webview

My WebView in my app are working fine, but when i load the URL= https://www.esheba.cnsbd.com/#/
Its automatically Redirecting to a Play store Link which is linked as download link in bottom of the website, But when i brows the link form browser is working fine. Please anyone tell me why its redirecting only in WebView ?
here is my codes are using.

**In XML**

```
<WebView
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/campaign_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**In Activity**

```
campaign_webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
campaign_webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
campaign_webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
campaign_webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
campaign_webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
campaign_webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
campaign_webview.setWebViewClient( new CustomClient());
campaign_webview.loadUrl(url);

private class CustomClient extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }

        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            handler.proceed();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.d("web_view: finish",url);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to redirect to Play Store if it is a Play Store link. So if that is what you want then you can use:

```
@Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView 
    view, String url) {
        
    if (url.startsWith("intent://")) {
    //load store
         try{
         Intent intent = Intent.parseUri(url, 
           Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);
         PackageManager packageManager = 
         context.getPackageManager();
         ResolveInfo info = 
          packageManager.resolveActivity(intent, 
           PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
       if (info != null) {
       context.startActivity(intent);
        }

         return true;

       }catch((ActivityNotFoundException e)
       {
          //If activity not found try to load it and also a display toast.


          Toast.makeText(context, "Activity not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          return false;
       }
   
   }
   else
   {
          //load url
          view.loadUrl(url);
           return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your replay, but i don't want to open playstore, actually i want to know why the the url = https://www.esheba.cnsbd.com/ 
not loading in webview it redirecting to playstore website.

Comment: Because when it redirects again then it starts with "intent://" maybe. Just log your url and see logcat to confirm this.